# Axios in React Native doesn't provide Form-Data headers

Tags: react-native, rest, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to upload a file via [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (Version `^0.26.0`) in React Native (Version `0.66.4`) with the following code:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', { 
  uri: 'aFilePathProvidedByTheImagePicker', 
  name: 'file.jpg', 
  type: 'image/jpg' 
});

const response = await this.axiosInstance.put('aCustomUrl', formData, {
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
 },
});
```

But it always fails with the status code 400. I tried the requested endpoint with [Postman](https://www.postman.com) and it works fine.

After some debugging and comparing the requests from axios and postman I found out that the `Content-Length` header is missing. Also a `boundary` in `Content-Type` isn't provided. See the screenshots below:

Postman:
[image: postman screenshot]

Reicht Native Debugging:
[image: react native debugger]

I also read about the `formData.getLengthSync()` but in react native it leads to the error `formData.getLengthSync is not a function`

Does anyone has a solution for this issue?

According to this [post](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406#issuecomment-1027207278) downgrading axios to version `0.24.0` works as a workaround.

(for debugging purpose I used the build in fetch-api which works as expected. but I'd prefer using axios for using a shared instance with request and response [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues is solved in Axios Version 0.27.2 (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4460#issuecomment-1115163147)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work but you could try to add content-type to headers

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formData .getBoundary(),
```

Comment: sadly the `getBoundary()` function is also not defined in react native, it's the same behavior like `formData.getLengthSync`

Comment: I just read my old project. I do exactly like you. Maybe the error comes from uri. How do you get uri?

Comment: with the dependency react-native-image-picker (https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker) as I tried to explain above: when I use the same form-data with the fetch api, it works perfectly. so axios has to do some strange hidden logic handling form data ...

Comment: Idk, my code still works for now, I use import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker'

Comment: according to this post: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4406#issuecomment-1027207278 I have to downgrade axios to version 0.24.0